# I'm trying to add application permissions in my microsoft graph access token

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm developing a microsoft teams tab (spa) application. I've added some permissions like
User.Read profile Chat.Read Chat.Read.All CallRecords.Read.All
issue is permission like User.Read profile Chat.Read are delegate permissions they are working fine. But when i try to get microsoft graph access token for application permission like Chat.Read.All or CallRecords.Read.All i'm getting a 403 forbidden error:

[image: error snip]

this is my authentication code

```
const authStart = () => {
        microsoftTeams.app.initialize().then(() => {
            // Get the tab context, and use the information to navigate to Azure AD login page
            microsoftTeams.app.getContext().then(async (context) => {
                var currentURL = new URL(window.location);
                // var scope = "User.Read CallRecords.Read.All Chat.Read email openid profile offline_access";
                var scope = "User.Read email openid profile offline_access Chat.Read Chat.ReadBasic Chat.ReadWrite CallRecords.Read.All";
                var loginHint = context.user.loginHint;

                const msalConfig = {
                    auth: {
                        clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_AZURE_APP_REGISTRATION_ID,
                        authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${context.user.tenant.id}`,
                        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
                    },
                    cache: {
                        cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
                    },
                };

                const msalInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

                const scopesArray = scope.split(" ");
                const scopesRequest = {
                    scopes: scopesArray,
                    redirectUri: window.location.origin + `/auth-end`,
                    loginHint: loginHint,
                    // prompt: "consent"
                };
                await msalInstance.loginRedirect(scopesRequest);
            });
        });
    }
```

I've already granted admin consent to every permission in microsoft azure active directory application setting yet same response is occuring.

[image: api permission snip from aad]

Also, when i decoded the jwt token, scope contained all my delegate permissions but all application permission where absent.

What am i missing? Or is their any other way to authenticate application permissions?

Answer (score 1):

When you use MSAL to sign in a user and request access to Microsoft Graph, you're requesting access to act *on behalf* of the signed-in user. This type of *delegated* access requires the client app be granted *delegated* permissions.

As the error suggests *CallRecords.Read.All* does not exist as a delegated permission. Also, the [API to get call records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) indicates that it doesn't support any delegated permission.

Application permissions (also known as "app roles") are used when an application is calling an API directly, *not* on behalf of a signed-in user. An app can only do this only if it is running in a secure backend service, where the application is able to secure a credential and use it to authenticate.

You cannot use application permissions (app roles) from a single-page app, because that app is just JavaScript running on the user's browser (or, in this example, in the browser control in the Teams client), you instead need to host a back-end service to obtain an app-only token to Microsoft Graph.

Comment: Yes, i've already setup a back-end service for that purpose and i'm calling all graph api's through that service. But still I don't understand how should I authenticate my application to call this api.

Comment: In your case, you're trying to use application permissions (Chat.Read.All or CallRecords.Read.All) in a context where a user is present (a Teams tab app), which is not supported. You should only use delegated permissions in this context.
If you need to access resources that require application permissions, you should consider creating a separate service that runs without a signed-in user. This service can be granted the necessary application permissions and can make calls to Microsoft Graph on behalf of your app.

Answer (score -1):

Like what Philippe mentioned, the Graph API you want to call [only supports application permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).  I completely agree with him and just want to add some more details in this question.

[image]

So it's correct that you already added and granted the application type of permissions. Then application permission can only be used by the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) in a daemon application, for example an web api project which doesn't have a UI page, so that it could generate an access token with `roles` claim inside it on behalf of the application itself(application type) but not on behalf of a user(delegated type).

Let's say you are having an asp.net core webapi backend service, then you could have codes like below in your controller to call this API using graph SDK. Please note, using client credential flow requires us to use `/.default` as the scope which is different from the scenario when using delegated permission.

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientId = "azure_Ad_app_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var users = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync();
```

You might try to have a sample in other programming language [in this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/sample-v2-code?tabs=apptype#service--daemon).